# How to remove all values in column A, that exist in column B?

Tags: excel, duplicates

I was wondering how to remove all values from column A, that exist in column B.

(column A has many duplicates, and I don't to remove duplicates)

I tried using remove duplicates. The only way I can do it is by using "Find and Replace" and replacing all values from column B in the entire sheet. This however is very slow.

[image]

Comment: How about using a formula like `IF(XLOOKUP(A3,B:B,B:B,"NOPE") = "NOPE",A3,"")`. Not tested but should work. Or is a helper column not allowed?

Comment: You could also try something like `=REPT(A3:A10,NOT(COUNTIF(B3:B10,A3:A10)))`

Comment: Many ways to accomplish this: `=IF(ISNA(XMATCH(A3:A10,B3:B10)),A3:A10,"")` or `=IF(COUNTIFS(B3:B10,A3:A10)=0,A3:A10,"")`

Comment: Try this  `=FILTER(A1:A8,A1:A8<>B1,"")`
the result will remove blank cell